# Google Play search keywords not showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: android, google-analytics, seo, google-play

i have an developer account on Google Play linked with Google Analytics (same google account)
I have an app there which i added to Google Analytics (Admin/[APP]/Property Setting/Link Apps From Google Play.

I'm able to see statistics for my apps like new/returning visitors, realtime data, e.t.c.

But **i can't find any data about which keywords are used in Google Play search to find my app**.

In Aquisitions/Google Play/Sources - there is just direct/none (i know this is used for keywords in the url but still it does not work)
If i add a second metric - keywords - still nothing :(

Again **i want to see which keywords are used in Google Play search to find my app** not the campaign or parameters in url that is clicked outside!

How to do this?